# updating packages after installing a new version of R

Tags: r, package, updates

I recently upgraded my R from 3.6 to the current version. I used the command `updateR()` from the `installR` package. When I was asked if I wanted to transfer all my packages from the old R version library to the library of the new R version, I agreed because I thought that I can just update the packages to the newer version afterwards, e.g. by using `update.packages()`. However, this did not work as I intended and I could not use the packages even after I updated them. I ended up just reinstalling R with the base packages and now I install packages whenever I need them, basically starting from zero. This is really frustrating and I would like to not do this again when I upgrade my R version the next time.

Can someone explain why my plan did not work as I intended and what is the most efficient way to keep everything up to date?

Kind regards

Comment: In what way could you not use the packages after updating?  Were the packages missing? Incompatible versions? Did you get some sort of error message? If so, what was it?

Comment: It should have worked but if you selected to keep old packages, they are still there in `R_HOME` so check and see. If they exist, you can copy that to the new R version's lib folder (?). I personally sometimes keep a `.txt` file of packages I needed and just read that and install whenever necessary.

Comment: I do not know unfortunately what the error message was exactly and I also do not have the packages left because I just deleted R completely and reinstalled it. Saving the package names in a text file seems like a nice idea for the future though.

Comment: R packages aren't guaranteed to be compatible across minor R versions, so it's generally a good idea to reinstall all packages from scratch when upgrading from one version to another (e.g., R 3.5 to 3.6). It's only patch version upgrades that maintain backward compatibility (e.g., R 3.6.0 to 3.6.1). For more info, check out https://rstats.wtf/maintaining-r.html#how-to-transfer-your-library-when-updating-r

Comment: Thanks a lot! So the ```update.packages()``` should only be used within a minor version and when the minor version changes I should always avoid it and use ```install.packages```? The name of the command is kind of misleading then I guess.